# I dont understand why im getting this error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ChoqueFrontal.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider collision) (at Assets/Scripts/ChoqueFrontal.cs:27)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChoqueFrontal : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DetectorDeChoque scriptChoqueCoche;
    private Movimiento scriptMovimiento;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scriptChoqueCoche = GetComponent<DetectorDeChoque>();
        scriptMovimiento = GetComponent<Movimiento>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        // Verifica si colisionó con un objeto que tiene el tag "Valla"
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Valla"))
        {
            scriptChoqueCoche.integridadCoche -= scriptMovimiento.velocidad;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags to your question. This is not a question about using Visual Studio, so the `[visual-studio]` tag isn't relevant. This is not written using the UnityScript language, as noted by your use of the C# tag and the fact it's C# code, so the `[unityscript]` tag is irrelevant. As for your question: something is null. The only things that (could) be null without knowing Unity, are `collision`, `collision.gameObject`, and `scriptChoqueCoche`.

Comment: [UnityScript tag usage information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info). I recommend reading it before posting again. C# and UnityScript are two different programming languages. C# is the preferred language for Unity development.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama UnityScript was even deprecated some years ago because it became very rarely used.